# Invoke-RestMethod 2 PHP_Curl

Tags: powershell

In PS I made this:

```
    $body=@{
        'code'='$code'
        'access_token'=$token
    }
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $body
```

Works perfect. How can I do the same in PHP Curl ?

Ive tryed something like this:

```
    $data = array("code" => $code, "access_token" => $token);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        "code=" . $code,
        "access_token=" . $token
        ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
    array('ContentType:text/plain')); 

     $result=curl_exec ($ch);
     print_r($result);
```

But I keep getting error like : Parameter token is missing.

Comment: Ok, I made it. Works perfectly. Thanks everyone.